# Excluding 'No Data' values from Elevation Profile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, 3d

I have derived an Elevation Profile from SRTM DEM (1ArcSec) using a polyline in ArcGIS 10.3. As shown in the below figure, the line passes through pixels having No Data values. However, these areas have been plotted in the resultant Elevation Profile.

I am intending to exclude portion of line having No Data values from the graph **without splitting my polyline** so I could show gap over there shown on graph. What is the optimal way to achieve this objective?
[image: Elevation Profile]

Comment: I have not done that, but the first thing I would try would be clipping the null data polygon out of the grid only.

Comment: As seen in the figure, despite of No Data values present below the line, the tool 'Profile Graph' available in ArcGIS 3D Analyst interpolates the values and displays on graphic which is not realistic.

Comment: Good question - I'm interested in a "proper" solution for this issue myself. My workaround: I'd recommend exporting the graph to an Excel or txt file and the process the data in Excel or R. I find ArcGIS profile graphs quite hard to handle anyway.

Comment: I am anxiously waiting for its solution. Although, I can make elevation profile using other available options, but didn't found any solution where missing patches of the data could be presented on graph as 'break'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to 3D Analyst, but I suggest either of the following:

1. Cut your line where there is no data and merge them back as a multi-part polyline and try again.
2. Try converting your line to points at regular intervals (whatever works for your purposes - maybe raster resolution or greater).  Then, use the **[point profile tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/using-the-point-profile-interactive-tool.htm)**. You should be able to eliminate points with no data relatively easily.